# Groovy project won't build in GGTS

Tags: java, groovy, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I have some Groovy code which will from fine from the command line, but when I try to use Springsource's GGTS fails:

```
Caught: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/cli/ParseException
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/cli/ParseException
at empyrean.Empyrean.run(Empyrean.groovy:20)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.cli.ParseException
... 1 more
```

I know this is because I have not got paths or something similar set correctly in GGTS but I cannot work out how to fix this (I used to use STS without a problem, this is the first time I have tried GGTS)

The non-compiling code is this (first line here is line 20 in the file):

```
def empyreanCli = new CliBuilder(usage:'empyrean [-d] <empyrean script>')

empyreanCli.d(longOpt:'debug',
'output debug data as we go')
empyreanCli.f(longOpt:'file',
'Empyrean script to run')
empyreanCli.u(longOpt:'usage',
'show this usage message')
def empyreanParse = empyreanCli.parse(args)

if (empyreanParse.u || args.size() == 0)
    empyreanCli.usage()
 else {
    def engine = new EmpyreanEngine()
    if (empyreanParse.d)
        engine.debug = true
    if (empyreanParse.f)
        engine.process(binsicParse.f)
    else
        engine.process(args[args.size() - 1])
 }
```

Which, as I say, runs fine from the command line...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the project to build I have to explictly add the necessary .jar files to the build path:

project -> properties -> java build path -> libraries -> add JARs

Comment: What jar files? I'm seeing the same thing. I have many dependencies defined as Grape Grabs, but the CliBuilder is the only one it's complaining about.